# Execute Multiple Lines in the Immediate Window of an Excel VBA workbook

Tags: excel, vba, immediate-window

Am I limited to execute only 1 command in the Excel VBA Immediate Window. Is there a way to execute multiple statements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the colon `:` key to concatenate multiple statements together. (ex: `MsgBox "msgBox1" : MsgBox "msgBox2"` will display two alert message boxes.